# Tree Diagram with Filesystem Branches

Tags: formatting, diagrams, tikz-styles, trees

I am trying to draw this tree diagram exactly:

[image]

I edited my code and it looks better, but still needs more work.

Here is the code and result:

```
\usetikzlibrary {trees}
\tikz [font=\footnotesize,grow=down, level 1/.style={->, sibling distance=20em},
,level 2/.style={->, sibling distance=8em}, level distance=3cm]

\node {Temporal Expressions}
   child { node {Tense}
      child { node {Past} }
      child { node {Present} }
      child { node {Future} }
  } ...
```

[image]

When I pass the following code to with this option to {Aspect} node:

```
 child [->, edge from parent fork down, sibling distance=30mm, level distance=30mm] { node {Aspect} ...
```

`
The output displays as this:

[image]

Any suggestions to fix?

Comment: Can someone help please?

Comment: After editing of your question a requirement is very different (and simpler) as before ...

Comment: And you change question again. What actually is your problem?

Comment: I think it is the same. I was trying to draw the diagram above. I saw no answers then I kept trying till I got some improved solution, but it still needs more correction to get the desired result. Is this clear now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `forest`, but it requires some manual adjustment because of the way the `folder` style interacts with the standard style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\forestset{fold/.style={folder, grow'=0, s sep=0pt},
    arr/.style={edge=-latex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={font=\footnotesize, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north}
    [LINGUISTIC TIME, s sep=1cm
        [TENSE, arr, for tree={fold}, before computing xy={s-=5mm}
            [Present]
            [Past]
            [Future]]
        [ASPECT, arr, l+=3.2mm, s sep=1cm
            [Grammatical, arr, for tree={fold}, before computing xy={s-=5mm}
                [Perfective]
                [Imperfective]
                [Progressive]]
            [Lexical, arr, l+=3.2mm, before computing xy={s-=5mm}
                [Atelic, forked edge, for tree={fold}, before computing xy={s-=5mm, l-=5mm}
                    [States]
                    [Activities]]
                [Telic, forked edge, for tree={fold}, before computing xy={s-=5mm, l-=5mm}
                    [Accomplishments]
                    [Achievements]]]]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks Sandy. This is very helpful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

- your question is not clear, sorry.
- your other image is simple to draw by use of `forest` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=0.2 cm]{standalone}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = 
{
    anchor = north,
    edge = {-Straight Barb, semithick},
    calign=edge midpoint,
    l sep = 7mm,
    s sep = 1mm,
}
[Temporal Expressions
    [TENSE
        [Present]
        [Past]
        [Futire]
    ]
    [ASPECT
        [grammatical
            [Perfective]
            [Imperfective]
            [Progressive]
        ]
        [Lexical
            [Atelic, 
                [States]
                [Activities]
            ]
            [Telic, 
                [Accomplishments]
                [Achievements]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the mix of tree styles is not simple (exceptions may be some forest gurus and the package author) to draw.

Comment: Thanks Zakro. Great help. And sorry for nor clarifying my question enough. This is good so far and, if you allow me, I am asking how draw the same tree in the picture. Anyway, many thanks again for the gentle help.