# how to have more control on the anchor location of a node other than defaults?

Tags: tikz-pgf

A tikz node has anchor points `south`, `north` etc.. also `south west` and `south east` etc...

But in this diagram below, I'd like to draw a line from a node starting not at exactly `south west` but half way between `south west` and `south`. i.e. shifted more to to the right from the south west corner so it looks better.

How does one create a new anchor location in general to use to draw lines from other than those buildin?

An example will make this clear. This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
    
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {differential equation};
    %
    \node [block, below right=1cm and -1.5cm  of init] (secondOrder) {second order};
    %
       \node [block, below=1cm of secondOrder] (linearSecondOrder) {linear};
       \node [block, right=1cm of linearSecondOrder] (nonlinearSecondOrder) {non-linear};
    %
    \node [block, below left=1cm and 1cm  of init] (firstOrder) {first order};
    %
       \node [block, below=1cm of firstOrder] (firstOrderDegree1) {degree 1};
           %
           \node [block, below right=.5cm and -1.2cm of firstOrderDegree1] (linearFirstOrder) {linear};
           \node [block, below=.5cm of linearFirstOrder]  (separable) {separable};
           \node [block, below=.5cm of separable]   (bernoulli) {Bernoulli};
       %
       \node [block, left=1cm of firstOrderDegree1] (firstOrderDegreeHigher) {higher degree};
    %
    \node [block,   below right=1cm and 4.5cm of init] (higherOrder) {higher order};
     

    \path [line] (init) -- (firstOrder);
    \path [line] (init) -- (secondOrder);
    \path [line] (init) -- (higherOrder);
    %
    \path [line] (secondOrder) -- (linearSecondOrder);
    \path [line] (secondOrder) -- (nonlinearSecondOrder);
    %
    \path [line] (firstOrder) -- (firstOrderDegree1);
    \path [line] (firstOrder) -- (firstOrderDegreeHigher);
    %
    \path [line] (firstOrderDegree1.south west) -- (linearFirstOrder.west);
    \path [line] (firstOrderDegree1.south west) -- (separable.west);
    \path [line] (firstOrderDegree1.south west) -- (bernoulli.west);    
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Generates this

[image]

Actually what I'd like to do is the following, but I think this is harder so I am try first to see if I can change the anchor location first:

[image]

The above is better, but I do not know how do the above, since I do not know the locations to draw the lines from/to. So I'll settle for the first choice for now if possible.

Comment: With `forrest` is easy. See examples in  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649172/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/635418/ or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641950/.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, I knew about forest but did not use it much, may be one time. I wanted first to see if I can do all this directly without using external packages such as forest or tree as this way I have more control of things and how to arrange things. If this does not work, will try forest or tree packages.

Comment: Nodes have "degree anchors". For example `<node>.210` means: At the point on the border where a line would cross that starts form the center of the node, rotated by 210 degrees (where 0 degrees is identical to `east`). In your case, `firstOrderDegree1.240` could maybe work, since `firstOrderDegree1.270` would be the same as `firstOrderDegree1.south`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks. Yes, `firstOrderDegree1.220` worked. If you have suggestion how to do the second version (preferred one) that will be great. The problem  I do not know how to draw the vertical line I showed in the second version. If not, will use your degree option for now.

Comment: You can use the " vertical/horizontal line-to" operator `|-` (there is also `-|`). Combine this with a "degree anchor" and you would get `\path [line] (firstOrderDegree1.220) |- (linearFirstOrder.west);`. This first draws a vertical line that starts at `firstOrderDegree1.220` and then adds a horizontal line to `linearFirstOrder.west`.

Comment: How much to the right? An absolute length? → `([xshift=<value>]<name>.south west)`. A relative length, say halfway between `.south west` and `.south`? → `($(<name>.south west)!.5!(<name>.south)$)`. The answers to [Q247821](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/247821) show some PGF solutions that add special anchors.

Comment: @JasperHabicht wow, that worked. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `forest`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!20,
    minimum height=1.5cm, minimum width=2cm,
    align=center, base=b,
    s sep=1cm, l sep=.5cm,
    if level<=2{edge=-latex}{edge=red},
}
[differential\\equation
    [first order, calign=last
        [higher\\degree][degree 1, for tree={grow'=0, folder}, s sep=.5cm, before computing xy={l-=.845cm}
            [linear][separable][Bernoulli]
        ]
    ]
    [second order, calign=first
        [linear][nonlinear]
    ]
    [higher order, fit=band]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```